# d3 x-axis with one incorrect value

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I'm using d3 to create a multi-series line chart. This is working great with no errors, except that one of the labels on the x-axis is totally incorrect.

I think it might be something to do with how I parse the dates; e.g. "12:00" => 12PM

```
var parseTime = d3.time.format("%H:00").parse;
```

But "00:00" turns to "1900".

Please see the jsfiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/cjNZ6/.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is because of the [multi-scale time format](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#format_multi) that D3 uses by default. You don't specify a year in your dates, so it assumes 1900.

To fix, simply specify a tick format explicitly:

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
  .scale(x)
  .tickFormat(d3.time.format("%I %p"))
  .orient("bottom");
```

Complete demo [here](http://jsfiddle.net/cjNZ6/1/).